# Tightest finite wait loop possible in AVR8

Tags: avr, delay, assembler

I need a wait delay function with fine grained control of the delay. I came up with the fairly standard way

```
      ldi   Rx, N
lp:   dec   Rx
      brne  lp
```

This code takes precisely N * 3 cycles to execute (the final "brne", leaving the loop, takes one cycle less, compensating the extra cycle used by the "ldi").

One way to achieve finer control would be to add two copies, one with an extra "nop", the other with two extra "nop"s. Next to complications with really short delays (need to take the execution time of the code branching to the correct copy into account), this solution is ugly. Therefore my question:

Is there a way to create a finite wait loop where the execution of one loop takes only two cycles (or even one)?

Comment: Do you really want a "finite" delay or a "variable" loop. Your example code is a variable loop, where N is the variable. A finite delay could just use the basic NOP instruction, add as many as needed in sequence. Not very efficient but it would be the finest grained control.

Answer (score 3):

No loop can be shorter than one iteration, as it would mean there can be no loop code to begin with.

Many compilers handle this scenario by introducing a macro or inline function to wait requested amount of cycles (or time), and they implement it as a combination of loop and additional NOPs, or any combination of them, to precisely introduce a delay of the requested amount with the granularity of one clock cycle.

The compiler is then free to call or inline any available type of delay function to implement what user requested.

So, the tightest loops in 8-bit AVR assembly take three cycles per iteration and additional setup code for loading an 8-bit register with the immediate value.

The instruction set has no instructions to do tighter loops than decrementing a variable and branching back to decrement it again if it was non-zero.

Comment: You begin your answer with a commonplace which might not apply. What immediately comes to my mind is that some architectures (68k derivatives for instance) have a combined decrement-and-branch-if-not-zero instruction, hence a loop consisting of only one instruction (as opposed to two from the code in my question) can be constructed. Also more fancy looping code is feasible (like skipping an absolute jump using the "sbrs" instruction), as I wrote mine is just standard stuff.

Comment: I'm just not familiar enough with the AVR8 instruction set to see if such optimisations are possible in AVR8 or not, and I'd appreciate an answer by someone who is.

Comment: @PeterRottengatter OK, well, I did say shorter loop is not possible. An 8-bit AVR has no such instructions to implement a loop shorter than the 3 cycles to decrement a register and branching back if it is not zero. This is a delay loop, while academically intriguing, it really does not matter how efficiently you waste time in a loop, and under normal circumstances, the additional NOPs to make a finer grade granularity than 3 cycles are usually not important.